# Connecting dots on scatterplot with lines correlating to colormap

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter

I am very new to the world of coding and I am trying to complete an assignment for class. I was able to plot the colormap but I don't know how to connect the various dots. I know line collection can be used but I simply don't understand it. Here is what I have so far.

```
plt.figure(figsize=(13,7))
plt.plot(radius_data['AtomicRadius'], radius_data['Group'],linestyle='dashed',
         linewidth=.5)
plt.scatter(radius_data['AtomicRadius'],radius_data['Group'], s=10, c=radius_data['Period'], cmap='ocean')
plt.colorbar(label='Period')
plt.title('Correlation Between Atomic Radius, Group and Period')
plt.xlabel('Atomic Radius', fontsize=12)
plt.ylabel('Group', fontsize=12)
plt.xlim(0,3.5)
plt.ylim(1,18)
plt.grid()
```

My graph:

[image: My graph]

Comment: Did you look at [this tutorial](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/multicolored_line.html)? If so, where did you get stuck?

Comment: Yes I did but my question is related to the solution given here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59086837/connecting-dots-in-a-2d-scatterplot-with-a-color-as-a-third-dimension